# Touchscreen scroll issue 2in1 Convertible Document viewer

Tags: touchscreen, scrolling, gnome-documents

When I use Document Viewer in tablet mode, moving the Document with one finger on the screen works at first.

Then at some point (randomly), this is no longer so. When I try to move the content, it just behaves as if right-click the screen (shows context menu) or selects the text I try to slide away.
I can enforce this if I slide along the text (horizontally) and then when sth is selected long-hold on the text.

I can get out of this either by converting back to laptop mode or by right-clicking with an attached mouse on some point of the page. Then scrolling by sliding works again.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but unfortunately, I do not have the privilege to comment yet.

I did experience the same issue with my convertible using Okular on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. However, your mentioned 'fix' to right-click with a mouse pointed me towards the issue in my case: There's multiple modes, such as 'browse', 'text selection' or annotations in Okular, and scrolling with one finger only works in 'browse' mode in Okular. Right-clicking with a mouse let's the mode return to 'browse' mode, that's why scrolling worked again afterwards in my case.

If it is truly random in your case, this might only be part of a potential solution, but maybe this helps a little anyways.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround for touchscreen failed scrolling in Ubuntu Document Viewer.

Right Click and select "Reload"; this is currently fixing this problem for me.

CTRL+R does not seem to fix the issue restoring touchscreen scrolling, but Right Click -> Reload does restore scrolling.